# Where to put custom classes in a Rails app so they are globally available?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, singleton

I have a custom class located in `lib` and I want to create one instance of it that I can call anywhere in my Rails app--from controllers to rake tasks.

I can seem to do this with simple variables in an `initializers` file like this:

```
@foo = "bar"
```

and I can see `@foo` anywhere. How do I create an instance of my class so I can call it and its methods from anywhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds to me that you're trying to create a singleton instance of your class in lib.

Have a look at Ruby's singleton module in the ruby standard library http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/singleton/rdoc/index.html

Then you can just always access it by

`SomeClass.instance`

Answer (score 6):

In the lib directory: `lib/some_thing.rb`

Also see the comments in `config/application.rb` :

```
...
# Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable. 
...
```